# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in

Tags: centos

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in
```

I'm using php version 5.3. server centos 6

I installed php-mysql. i don't know much about centos. Another server which is centos 5.9 for the same code doesn't have such problem.

when i search on

```
yum search php-mysql
```

in centos 6 - php-mysql.x86_64 in centos 6

in centos-5.9 - php-mysql.x86_64, php53-mysql.x86_64, php54-mysql.x86_64.

May be i need php53-mysql.x86_64 in centos 6, how to get this extension on centos 6.?

Comment: Can you post the output of `php -i | grep mysql`?